# Install premium Wordpress theme with Composer

Tags: wordpress, composer-php

I've bought a "premium" theme on [Themeforest](http://themeforest.net/): [Avada](http://themeforest.net/item/avada-responsive-multipurpose-theme/2833226). I'd like to install this theme with [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) because it's a dependency (I'm using [Bedrock](https://github.com/roots/bedrock) as base). So I came across [this article](https://deliciousbrains.com/using-composer-manage-wordpress-themes-plugins/) where they suggest to make a custom package with the download link (example with some of there own Wordpress plugins WP Migrate DB Pro):

```
"require": {
    "deliciousbrains/wp-migrate-db-pro": "*"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "deliciousbrains/wp-migrate-db-pro",
            "type": "wordpress-plugin",
            "version": "1.5",
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://deliciousbrains.com/dl/wp-migrate-db-pro-latest.zip?licence_key=<LICENSE_KEY>&site_url=composer-test.dev"
            },
            "require": {
                "composer/installers": "v1.0.7"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Very nice, but then I've to maintain the version numbers by myself (I can't download an old version) and I don't like license keys in urls that much. But alright, I've tried but I need to be logged in on Themeforest else the download link (something like `http://themeforest.net/user/username/download_purchase/some-random-id?accessor=wordpress_theme`) won't work. I can try to trace the download link but Envato [recommends against download manager](https://help.market.envato.com/hc/en-us/articles/202500504), so I don't think this is allowed or the way to go. I've contacted Envato in the past because they recommend using Composer on there tutorial site [Tutsplus](http://tutsplus.com/) but they don't support this on there marketplace sites. Never got a reply.

Another method is to create my own GIT repository for Avada. No problem, so I've created it, added all the files with my own `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "username/wordpress-avada-theme",
    "type": "wordpress-theme"
}
```

Pretty simple, added a GIT tag with the version and it can be installed. Very nice! But... I've to maintain this by myself, if Avada releases a new version I've to remove all files from my Avada repo, add the new files with a new version number tag and then I can install the new version with Composer.

Another problem: plugins, Avada comes with some plugins which needs to be installed:

- Fusion Core
- Layerslider
- Revolution Slider

So I need 3 more repositories and I've to maintain them all if a new version comes out. So I've contacted [Theme Fusion](https://theme-fusion.com/), the creators of the theme. I don't think they doesn't work with version control and it's true, they use GIT but they are not allowed to give me access because of the conditions of Envato.

What other options do I have? I'm now just using Composer for Wordpress itself and all free plugins but I'd like to use it for my "premium" stuff too. Composer should make things easier, but when I've to maintain those repo's it's not. So for now I've putted Avada and it's plugins in the project repo but it doesn't feel good.

**EDIT:** Meanwhile I've found some interesting stuff in the Envato API which could make this possible, see my [issue on the wpackagist repository](https://github.com/outlandishideas/wpackagist/issues/129) which is a Composer mirror of the Wordpress plugin and theme directory.

Comment: Honestly I don't think you'll find a solution for this. As I work a lot with themeforest themes too (and did worked a bit with Avada by the way, which is an awfull theme tbh) I never figured a solution to properly handle version control. I would be interested if someone have a solution for this. Though for plugins if I remember correctly, Avada come with those plugins inside the theme folder, so if you update the theme the plugins are updated too.

Comment: I don't think neither but I haven't tried it on Stack Overflow, so hereby. The plugins that comes with Avada (and most other "premium" themes) are just `.zip` archives in a directory which needs to be installed as every other plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SatisPress](https://github.com/cedaro/satispress/) is what you are looking for. It's a tool that allows you to

> expose installed WordPress plugins and themes as Composer packages.

It's quite easy to setup and use:

1. Setup WordPress instance (e.g. `packages.example.com`)
2. Install and activate SatisPress
3. Install and active premium/paid packages (plugins/themes)
4. Provide license credentials to enable automatic updates
5. Add access token
6. Add repository and credentials to your `composer.json`/`auth.json` (or Private Packagist mirror)
7. Require premium package like this: `$ composer require satispress/my-private-plugin`

Refer to the documentation for more details: https://github.com/cedaro/satispress/blob/develop/docs/index.md

Note: I'm not affiliated with SatisPress or Private Packagist.

Answer (score 1):

I'm beta-ing a better solution to this. [Sign up here.](https://packagepeak.app/beta)

Though it won't currently handle nested dependencies (your Fusion Slider, Fusion Builder, etc) it will allow you to manage Avada (or other Envato purchases) via Composer and use version constraints properly:

`composer require theme-fusion/avada`

Or something to that effect.

Though Avada specifically screws this up because they have their patch updates that are applied outside the scope of normal WordPress updates. So to say nothing of that.

Comment: May I write a tiny MU plugin for you that disables built-in update in Avada?

Answer (score 0):

I've often seen people place purchased content under source control so it can be code reviewed when a new version is introduced. However, I believe the common practice for private packages is to use a private repository.

There are a handful of options when the private packages have `composer.json` files in them. Unfortunately, with WordPress that is often not the case. You can put a `packages.json` file on a webserver to use that URL as a composer repository.

The [test fixture](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/doc/fixtures/repo-composer-plain/packages.json) in the composer source can be used as an example for what is expected in that file. I tend to leave out the `version_normalized` field and provide `dist` information opposed to `source` (both can be provided).

What I had done in the past was place all of the packages on an internal server with a naming convention that reflected the relevant metadata so a composer repository could be generated easily from a bash script.

Something like `/archives/{package-type}/{vendor}/{name}_{version}.zip`

Answer (score -1):

Now you can install install themes and plugins purchased from Envato with this Composer plugin
https://packagist.org/packages/szepeviktor/composer-envato

```
composer require envato/avada
```

You need to install `composer-envato` globally!
See the [README](https://github.com/szepeviktor/composer-envato/blob/master/README.md) for configuration.

Comment: This is not recommended because it always downloads the latest version, nothing is and can be locked. It also doesn't work with plugins bundled with themes. SatisPress is the easiest way to go until Envato let us download older versions.

Comment: You're right Roy. I'll add this info in the README.