# Composer: Include version variable in package URL

Tags: url, package, composer-php, version

I have a package which contains it's version number in the download URL: `https://example.com/zip/4.3/package.zip`.

Is there a way to pass the version number as variable, so I don't have to change the package URL on every release?

Like this:

```
{
  "type": "package",
  "package": {
    "name": "example/package",
    "version": "4.3",
    "dist": {
      "type": "zip",
      "url": "https://example.com/zip/{$version}/package.zip"
    }
  }
}
```

I couldn't find any information on this topic in the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with [private-composer-installer](https://github.com/ffraenz/private-composer-installer) like this: `{%version}`

```
{
  "type": "package",
  "package": {
    "name": "example/package",
    "version": "4.3",
    "dist": {
      "type": "zip",
      "url": "https://example.com/zip/{%version}/package.zip"
    },
    "require": {
      "ffraenz/private-composer-installer": "^4.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an example using an environment variable:

```
{
  "type": "package",
  "package": {
    "name": "package-name/package-name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dist": {
      "type": "zip",
      "url": "https://example.com/package-name.zip?key={%PACKAGE_KEY}&version={%VERSION}"
    },
    "require": {
      "ffraenz/private-composer-installer": "^4.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to install _WordPress_ premium packages, SatisPress would probably be the better way to go. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59610919/1410103

Answer (score 0):

According to [composer/composer#6631](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6631) it is not possible to use variables in package URLs:

> [No, and I do not really see a good use-case for this either, so it is very unlikely to be included.](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6631#issuecomment-325029751)